# How to run anaconda on an emacs shell?

Tags: python, osx

I'm trying to get numpy and matplotlib to run from emacs so I downloaded anaconda. I've got it running on my terminal but I don't know how to run it in an m-x shell. I'm using mac os.

I've considered putting a command for it in .emacs.d/init_bash.sh but I don't know what that command would be or how that would work. How should I go about getting anaconda to work in an m-x shell?

Comment: You need to give us more information. If you can run it from a terminal, you should be able to run it from M-x shell. What command do you use from the terminal? What happens when you use the same command in M-x shell?

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is that Anaconda is not in your path, you can follow the instructions in the [Anaconda installation instructions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html#installing-in-silent-mode).
Basically all you need to do is add a line to you `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="<path to Anaconda installation location>/bin:$PATH"
```

then Anaconda should be accessible from `shell` mode in Emacs.

You could also check out the [Anaconda mode](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode) package for Emacs, it is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an environment and install Emacs from Conda. Your Conda-Emacs will start to use your environment python packages.